# Avoid loops and dictionaries when using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have some code which reads in some csv files of stock data (can be hundreds of thousands of lines), then uses `df.iterrows()` to loop through and perform operations based on cell values.

The reason why questions I've seen don't seem to apply as much here is because of the number of different of options which need computing: I have several different `if row['Action'] == 'Some string'` within the loop, which have nested if statements with further processing.

To add further complexity, each row's action only affects a certain stock item (there is only one action per row, so for example if a stock item is ordered that would take up one row), so to account for this, in my code I have a number of dictionaries which store values for each stock item, and then the if statements affect only the specific stock item.

Then once the dataframe has been traversed I do the required processing based on the dictionaries. (This is things like `Target_Stock_Quantity = (ID_Use_Totals / args.days) * 15`)

The question I have relates to how when looking up how to speed up pandas processing it is clear that looping is a deadly sin, and so I want to know what other options are available.

A simple version of my code would be:

```py
IDs = # list of IDs
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in args.csv], ignore_index = True) 

ID_Use_Totals = {}
ID_Order_Dates = {}
ID_Received_Dates = {}
ID_Refs = {}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Stock Item'] in IDs:
        if row['Action'] == 'Use':
            if row['Stock Items'] in ID_Use_Totals:
                ID_Use_Totals[row['Stock Item']] += abs(int(float(row['Qty'])))
            else:
                ID_Use_Totals[row['Stock Item']] = abs(int(float(row['Qty'])))
        elif row['Action'] == 'Order':
            ...
```

Where each `elif row['Action'] == ''` has different processing.

I am specifically looking for code which can replace `df.iterrows()`, but I would also appreciate tips/links to information about how to speed up pandas processing/using oop in pandas if anyone knows of good resources. Many thanks in advance

Comment: Consider Vectorization. This is a great [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-your-pandas-loop-71-803-times-faster-805030df4f06)

Comment: so simple to refactor to use `loc[]` and 'apply()` and it will run so much faster

Comment: I have looked into vectorisation but I'm struggling to see how it is good for returning values, I have expanded in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63168583/using-vectorisation-to-add-row-values-to-dictionary-python

Comment: Also I'm not sure how simple it is to use ````[loc]```` and ````apply()```` because as far as I can see online they are used for changing series objects but I am not looking to change anything in my dataframe, just retrieve values from it